# Alchemy API: How to get transaction history including failed and pending transactions for a specific wallet address?

Tags: transactions, wallets, pending-transactions, alchemy, failed-transaction

In React I'm building a transaction history screen to list succeeded, failed and pending Polygon transactions. Using `alchemy_getAssetTransfers` I can retrieve the transaction history for a specific wallet address, but it seems like its only returning the succeeded ones. How can I also show failed and pending? I would like to list them all together for a specific wallet address.

There's a method called `alchemy_getTransactionReceipts` that returns a transaction status prop but it only works on a single transaction and I need to get the whole history at once.

There's a method `alchemy_pendingTransactions` using WebSockets, I guess this is the right one for showing the pending ones?

Ps. It seems like the `polygonscan.com/address/{walletAddress}` endpoint returns all kinds of useful data such as transaction status etc. Is this endpoint accessible somehow? I can't seem to find it in their docs.